# How to redirect some pages in Google chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am using `chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest` in my **background** script to listen to all request a user is making. My extension now is just a manifest and this bg script.

I then check if the url matches a regex:

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
     checkRedirect, {urls: ["<all_urls>"]}, ["blocking"]
);

function checkRedirect(details) {   
    var location = getLocation(details.url);

    if(/some_regex/.test(details.url)) {
        var redirect_url = 'http://some_redirect.com' + location.pathname;
        chrome.tabs.update({url: redirect_url});
    }

    return {cancel: false}; 
}

function getLocation(href) {
    var l = document.createElement('a');
    l.href = href;
    return l;
};
```

So if a user enters a page or clicks on a link to that page, I'd like to redirect him.
The code above works almost fine; **the problem** is when the page requests e.g. CSS then those CSS end up on the user screen.

---

So what I'd want is to only filter requests to pages / clicks.. how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Limit event notifications to the top-level frame by setting [`types`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest#property-RequestFilter-types) to `['main_frame']` (use `['main_frame', 'sub_frame']` if you want to include frames as well).

Although the previous suggestion will fix your problem, I suggest to go a step further and get rid of `chrome.tabs.update`. Use [`redirectUrl`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest#property-BlockingResponse-redirectUrl) to replace the previous request with a redirect to the desired URL.

If your URL-pattern matching method is very simple, expressible as a [match pattern](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns), incorporate the filter in the ["urls"](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest#property-RequestFilter-urls) key of the webRequest API filter. This will reduce your extension's impact on your browser's performance.

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(function(details) {
    var location = getLocation(details.url); // getLocation defined in question
    var redirect_url = 'http://some_redirect.com' + location.pathname;
    return { redirectUrl: redirect_url };
}, {
    types: ['main_frame', 'sub_frame'],
    urls: ['*://*/*some_pattern*']
}, ['blocking']);
```

Note: Do not use `<all_urls>` if you are not prepared to handle non-http(s) requests.

Comment: Thank you very much. But what do you mean by *Do not use <all_urls> if you are not prepared to handle non-http(s) requests.* ?

Comment: @user3733425 `<all_urls>` includes other schemes such as `file:`*, `ftp:`, etc. If you only want to intercept http(s) requests, then you should use `*://*/*`. The scheme wildcard expands to `http://*/*` and `https://*/*`.