# Chrome Extension to solve Mixed Content?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, https, xmlhttprequest

I would extremely appreciate some help with the following issue:

I have a payment web app hosted in IIS and configured for SSL. I need to integrate a POS terminal (or pin-pad) with a static IP that's not SSL compatible. I can talk to it running the site without SSL (HTTP to HTTP), but not HTTPS to HTTP - obviously getting "Mixed Content ..." error as Chrome doesn't allow that. I don't need to care about other browsers, but I can't run my site HTTP and as mentioned terminal doesn't support HTTPS.

Now, before you mark it as duplicate - I've read: 
[sending request from https to http from chrome extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37487784/sending-request-from-https-to-http-from-chrome-extension), 
[Chrome extension - Disable Blocking of Mixed Content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36348559/chrome-extension-disable-blocking-of-mixed-content) 
[Since v38, Chrome extension cannot load from HTTP URLs anymore, workaround?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26285539/since-v38-chrome-extension-cannot-load-from-http-urls-anymore-workaround).

And it looks like Chrome extension might provide a solution. I don't have any experience with Chrome extensions though, but comfortable with JavaScript. I would prefer to avoid chasing something that would result in a dead-end. So, my question is - am I on the right path? If so, how do I go about implementing this? How do I go about delegating the ajax post call to the extension?

Any thoughts, ideas, tips, suggestions would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are going to use chrome-extension, do you want everyone who visits your payment site install the extension first? If the answer is yes, then sure, chrome-extension can help with that. Take at the following guide:

1. [Cross-Origin XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr), it tells you that background page can send request to http site, even if current page is https
2. [`chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest#event-onBeforeRequest), it tells you that you could redirect a http(s) request.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I can insure user installs extension. Can you maybe provide some example, code sample? Completely new to this extensions thing and looks like tutorials/samples are not very well maintained by google...

Comment: @lentyai, hey lentyai, for option 1, above official link has given wonderful samples, just to make an ajax call in background page; for option 2, you could take a look at Rob W's great answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25059601/how-to-redirect-some-pages-in-google-chrome-extension

Comment: Went with a different solution, but will still accept as an answer. Thanks!

Comment: @lentyai can you tell what solution you went with?

Comment: Lucky, sorry for delay - I used iFrame.

Comment: Hey @lentyai - can you show your solution (or give some advice)?
I have EXACLY the same trouble with POS terminals and i was trying to resolve with iframes, but I don't have a clue how to do it.